# How to neatly create association matrix based on cluster result in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Say for five patterns, using clustering method, they are assigned three classes with label `[1,1,2,1,3]`, now I want to generate an 5*5 association matrix based on that, where in the matrix `1` means they are in same cluster and 0 means they are in different clusters.

Is there any neat implementation in Python can be used of doing that? Actually, since I am using scikit-learn to generate the clustering result, I am not quite sure if there is a some functions can be used to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the desired output you can generate the matrix with list comprehension:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> l = [1,1,2,1,3]
>>> res = [[int(x == y) for y in l] for x in l]
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
[[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a *library* to do this.

This is elementary math/logic and can neatly expressed in e.g. `numpy`.

Use the label vector, repeat it to square form and it's transpose `rep == rep.transpose()` is your association matrix.

Doing this in numpy will be more efficient than a pure python solution with list-of-lists-of-integer-objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build an association matrix as part of a voting mechanism, you can elaborate @niemmi answer even further:

```
#Declare the weight of each vote
vote = 1 / len(estimators)
#co_association matrix is 5X5 (5 patterns)
co_association = np.zeros((5, 5))

#for each of your estimators
for est in estimators:
    #fit the data and grab the labels
    est.fit(data)
    labels = est.labels_
    #find all associations and transform it into a numpy array
    res = [[int(i == j) for i in labels] for j in labels]
    res = np.array(res)
    #Vote and update the co_association matriz
    res = res * vote
    co_association = co_association + res
```